# Visual Basic - Check a recordset field type in an If statement

Tags: vba, ms-access, types

I'm trying to check the datatype of a field in a table, to have the code do one thing if it is of Text type and another if it is of any other type. Below is the code that I have but I don't think I have the third line right at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Set dbExample = CurrentDb
Set rsTester = dbExample.OpenRecordset("tester", dbOpenDynaset)
If TypeOf rsTester!exampleField Is Text Then
    'Does what the code needs to do
Else
    'Does what the code needs to do
End If
rsTester.Close
```

Comment: Did you actually compile to make sure your third line is wrong (if it's wrong)?

Comment: Yes I did - it tells me that Text isn't defined

Comment: Are you sure that Text is the valid data type? It should probably be String

Comment: When I use String I get a syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TypeOf` isn't used with DAO `Field` objects. What you want to do is something more like

```
If rsTester("exampleField").Type = dbText Then
    ' do the thing
Else
    ' do the other thing
End Select
```

Comment: Why use ADO ? The native model in Access is DAO.

Comment: @iDevlop - because it's been a century or three since I used DAO (and that from VB3, not Access) :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can test the Type property of a field in a TableDef object.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim td As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb
With db.TableDefs("Factures")
    Debug.Print .Fields("nofact").Type
End With
```